# difference between css flex-box and react-native in flex:1 property

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I found css **flexbox** flex property i.e. **flex:1** does not work as same as react-native flex:1.It works differently in **react-native** grid system. need help to understand

> flex:1

as react-native perspective.

Answer (score 2):

**According to Documantation**

*Flexbox works the same way in React Native as it does in CSS on the web, with a few exceptions. The defaults are different, with **flexDirection** defaulting to **column** instead of **row**, and the **flex** parameter only supporting a single number.*

For more information refer this [Layout with Flexbox](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox)